# Spine.List not rendering in the view

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, spine.js, eco

I'm working on a SpineJs app that has the following setup: Posts (essentially chat rooms), which each have multiple messages in them, exactly like a text message stream, or even a chat room stream. I am having problems getting the `Spine.List` functionality to work though, but i suspect i'm not doing something quite right…

I have created a Gist of my controller and views: https://gist.github.com/coolbox/6880967

**post.main.coffee**

```
Spine   = require('spine')
$       = Spine.$

# Models
Post       = require('models/post')
Session    = require('models/session')
Message    = require('models/message')

class Show extends Spine.Controller
  className: 'show content-area'

  events:
    'submit form': 'submit'

  elements:
    '.messages' : 'messages'

  constructor: ->
    super
    @html require('views/posts/show')
    @active @change

    @list = new Spine.List
      el: @messages
      template: require('views/messages/message')
      selectFirst: true

    @list.bind 'change', @render

    Post.bind 'refresh', @render
    Message.bind 'create', @change

  render: =>
    return if !@postId
    @post = Post.exists(@postId)

    if @post
      messages = @post.messages
      @list.render(messages)

    @html require('views/posts/show')(@post)

  change: (params) =>
    if params.id != @postId
      @postId = params.id

    if Session.first()
      Post.fetch
        id: @postId

    @render()

  submit: (e) =>
    e.preventDefault()
    message = Message.fromForm(e.target)
    message.save()


class Main extends Spine.Stack
  className: 'main stack'

  controllers:
    show: Show

module.exports = Main
```

**show.eco**

```
<ul class='messages'></ul>

<div class='footer'>
  <form class='new-message'>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<%= @id %>">
    <textarea name='body' placeholder='Type your message here…' autofocus='autofocus'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' value='Send'>
  </form>
</div>
```

**message.jeco**

```
<li class='item'>
  <%= @body %>
</li>
```

You'll be able to see that the 'messages' that belong to a Post are included as an array of objects within the Post object. My suspicion is that because the messages aren't Spine objects that they won't work with my `Spine.list`. If so, what is my best option?

As a heads up, i'm not getting any errors in the console and nothing is rendering on screen, apart from a few other `nav` bits and pieces i have.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used Spine.List, but as far as I can List doesn't expect your 'messages' to be Spine objects, just an array.  It may help to look at the source to Spine.List, it's just 43 lines: https://github.com/spine/spine/blob/dev/src/list.coffee.

Comment: Code has to go in the question, not on 3rd party services like Github.

Comment: Ooops, didn't know that. I've included it in the question now.

Comment: @jewel Thanks, i don't know why i didn't think to check the docs, duh! Yeah i've actually decided that Spine.List isn't what i want to use now i've had a look at them. Their use is intended for more of a tabbing situation i think, which isn't what im trying to achieve. I think i'm just going to go with looping through the messages on the show view.